# absolute path problem drupal

Tags: javascript, drupal, path

I have installed xampp and in the htdocs folder I have a folder called drupaldev. I need to give reference to a image in javascript but my images doesn't display. my image is in `C:\xampp\htdocs\drupaldv\sites\all\modules\finder\images` folder and I refered it in javascript as `/drupaldv/sites/all/modules/finder/images`... What could be the reason for this... Please can someone explain... Thanks a lot!

Comment: More information, please. What is the full local path of the image? What is the current output rendered to the page?

Comment: http://localhost/drupaldv/sites/all/modules/finder/images/check.jpg when I use this in my browser it displays the image... Image is in C:\xampp\htdocs\drupaldv\sites\all\modules\finder\images\check.jpg

Comment: Can you post your JavaScript?

Comment: finally I found the reason, it's an issue of having 2 window.addEvent('domready', function()..... Thanks a lot for the concern everyone :-)))))

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Drupal.setting.basepath variable. This gives you the document root for the drupal instance you are running. Append the rest of the required file path to this variable.

Hope this helps!!